# How can I permanently unhide invisible files on mac (not just make invisible files visible!)?

Tags: macos, finder, command-line

I have a few invisible files. I want to turn them into visible files. That is, **I do not just want to make my invisible files show up in the Finder** (I have that already, -they all show up) - *but I'd like to turn them into normal, unhidden files, just like all my other files.*

How can I do this on my Mac?

Comment: How did you term them invisible in the first place? Can you share some details about file names and the content of the "Get Info" pane?

Comment: Are these files which are usually hidden by macOS, or files you have created?

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways that I know of to *hide* a file on macOS:

1. Start the file name with a `.` (period) -- this is carry over from Unix systems and the Finder still to this day honors the tradition.
2. Assign the *hidden* attribute to the file. To do this, you would use the `chflags` command-line program via the Terminal app.

Thus to reveal all hidden items in the Finder, one would have to do two things:

1. Enable in Finder viewing of items that start with a `.` (period). This is what you have already done.
2. Find all files and folders with the *hidden* attribute and remove the attribute with `chflags nohidden`. You can script this with various command-line programs or you could use something like Batchmod application do to so for you.

Comment: Note that `chflags nohidden` will not work on any SIP protected directory or file as long as it's enabled. Also, `sudo chflags nohidden` will be needed on any directory or file owned by `root`, unless logged in as `root` in Terminal.